# Chamada de JavaScript dentro do PHP

Tags: php

Boa tarde, estou com dificuldades de executar um código JavaScript dentro do PHP. A minha intenção é ao usuário errar o login e senha aparecer uma mensagem na tela de Login avisando o mesmo que ele errou, isso usando JavaScript fazendo que o mesmo retire uma classe chamada "classe-invisivel".

Segue o código a seguir:

```
if ($resultado > 0) {
        logaUsuario($usuario->id, $usuario->nome, $usuario->grupo);
        header("Location: index.php");
    } else {
        echo "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
                function mostrarErro() {
                var alerta = $('.alerta-erro');

                alerta.removeClass('classe-invisivel');
                setTimeout(function() {
                alerta.addClass('classe-invisivel');
                }, 6000);
            }
                mostrarErro();
                window.location.replace('login.php');
              </script>";
    }
```

Não consigo ver onde estou errando. Alguém saberia me orientar, alguma dica?

Obrigado!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Fazer a chamada dessa forma é uma má pratica. Coloque a função em um arquivo JS e escape para a página de login no evento onload da tag body a chamada da função mostrarErro().

```
<?php

// Suas regras de login
$erroLogin = false;

if ($resultado > 0) {
    //Se houver sucesso
    logaUsuario($usuario->id, $usuario->nome, $usuario->grupo);
    header("Location: index.php");

} else {
    //Se falhar
    $erroLogin = true;        
}


[....]
<html>
    <head>
    <script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
            function mostrarErro()
            {
                var alerta = $('.alerta-erro');
                alerta.removeClass('classe-invisivel');

                setTimeout(function() {
                    alerta.addClass('classe-invisivel');
                }, 6000);
            }
              </script>
    </head>
    <body <?php echo (isset($erroLogin) && $erroLogin === true) ? 'onload="javascript:mostrarErro();"' : null ;?>>

    [...]

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela orientação que isso não é uma boa prática e pela ajuda!